# Celery and Celerybeat are running, but don't run tasks

Tags: django, nginx, redis, celery, celerybeat

I'v already checked my code on local server and I'm sure everything is ok on my code. So it seems something is wrong on server configuration. I have a linux server (Ubuntu 16.04) and installed nginx, redis , ...Also I created configuration files for celery and celerybeat as below:

- /etc/init.d/celeryd
- /etc/default/celeryd
- /etc/init.d/celerybeat
- /etc/default/celerybeat

I checked their status ,both of them are running but when I check beat.log it doesn't do anything and only shows 'starting ...'

celeryd file:

```
# Names of nodes to start
CELERYD_NODES="worker"

# Absolute or relative path to the 'celery' command:
CELERY_BIN="/home/amirali/AwesomeApp/awesome_env/bin/celery"


# App instance to use
CELERY_APP="AwesomeApp"


# Where to chdir at start. Where your manage.py is...
CELERYD_CHDIR="/home/amirali/AwesomeApp"

# Extra command-line arguments to the worker
CELERYD_OPTS="--time-limit=300 -Ofair --concurrency=8"

# Set logging level to DEBUG
CELERYD_LOG_LEVEL="INFO"

# %n will be replaced with the first part of the nodename.
CELERYD_LOG_FILE="/var/log/celery/%n%I.log"
CELERYD_PID_FILE="/var/run/celery/%n.pid"

# Workers should run as an unprivileged user.
#   You need to create this user manually (or you can choose
#   a user/group combination that already exists (e.g., nobody).
CELERYD_USER="celery"
CELERYD_GROUP="celery"

# If enabled pid and log directories will be created if missing,
# and owned by the userid/group configured.
CELERY_CREATE_DIRS=1
```

celerybeat file:

```
  File: /etc/default/celerybeat                                                                                                                                                              
  CELERYBEAT_LOG_LEVEL="info"
  # Absolute or relative path to the 'celery' command:
  CELERY_BIN="/home/amirali/AwesomeApp/awesome_env/bin/celery"

  CELERYBEAT_USER="celery"
  CELERYBEAT_GROUP="celery"
  # App instance to use
  # comment out this line if you don't use an app
  CELERY_APP="AwesomeApp"
  # or fully qualified:
  #CELERY_APP="proj.tasks:app"

  # Where to chdir at start.
  CELERYBEAT_CHDIR="/home/amirali/AwesomeApp"

  # Extra arguments to celerybeat
  CELERYBEAT_OPTS="--schedule=/var/run/celery/celerybeat-schedule"
  export DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE="AwesomeApp.settings"
```

Comment: What are you expecting here? Have you sent jobs yourself, using `.delay` for example or are there scheduled jobs that are meant to run?

Comment: Yes, I created my tasks file and it works with 'celery -A proj beat -l info' command. the problem comes up when I want to run worker as a daemon.

Comment: So what is the problem with the worker? What do you expect to see when it runs and what are you seeing?

Comment: I except to see scheduler messages in the beat.log. something like "Scheduler: Sending due task [task_name]". but it only shows "beat: Starting..."

Comment: The task is very simple, it must send a string to my telegram channel.

Answer (score -2):

When we had to implement celery periodic tasks, it turned out `celery-beat` did not work properly, it had just stopping launch tasks in some moment.

After some tests we decided do not waste our time on it anymore and rely on linux `crontab` utility